# Does Safe Publication and Initialization Safety work in .NET?

Tags: java, .net, multithreading, concurrency

I found the book Java Concurrency in Practice to be an excellent guide to writing multithreaded code for Java. I am wondering to what extent the general principals described in the book apply to .Net. I am not interested in rolling my own lock free code – I just want to use solid, understandable techniques and exploit existing synchronized and concurrent APIs. To that extent, the key takeaways from the book for me were:

1. Locking – states changes made inside a lock in one thread are visible to all other threads inside a locks on the same object. No doubt this works in .NET and would be sufficient to write thread safe programs but it leads to unnecessary locking if we cannot rely on the following mechanisms.
2. Safe Publication – The latest state of an effectively immutable object (an object which is not changed after publication) is visible to all threads provided one of the following holds. Note that seeing the latest state of a reference to an object is not the necessarily same as seeing the latest state of the object itself – in Java safe publication works because of the transitive nature  of the happens-before relationship.

   - Access to it’s references are synchronized via locks in all threads
   - It is referenced via a volatile variable
   - It is published from a synchronized or concurrent collection.
3. The latest state of properly constructed immutable objects with only final fields (readonly in .NET) are thread safe regardless of how they are published.

I would hope all of these work otherwise it makes life unnecessarily difficult, but from what I have ready the model for .Net (at least as it is specified) is quite weak. Has anyone tried to construct a happens-before model for .NET? I think this an area which badly needs to be addressed in .Net. As far as I know there isn’t an equivalent book for .Net which can give the same ‘level of comfort’ – it seems that at least part of the problem is the lack of a well defined memory model for .NET.

Comment: Ok, I understand your concerns, but I cannot discern any concrete question here. Or are you just starting a conversation about memory models and fences?

Comment: @Tudor - The question is what I have put in the title. Admittedly, it’s a quite a big question with multiple parts.  What I am looking for is a set of simple rules off what is safe in .net – as I mentioned I don’t want to roll my own lock free code – I just want to leverage existing thread safe library code without employing unnecessary locking.  I’m happy to accept suggestions on how to improve the question – perhaps I should break it up into multiple questions?

Comment: It's probably better to break it down. Then when you have a set of smaller questions, you can also use the search here on SO. I'm pretty sure I've seen the answers to at least some of them given before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general concepts are the same. The differences between the Java and .NET memory model need to be taken into account though. This usually involves using the [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) functions (in [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html)), [VolatileRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.volatileread.aspx) / [VolatileWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.volatilewrite.aspx) or [explicit memory barrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier.aspx).

There are two memory models specified for .NET. A weak memory model specified in Section 12, Partition I of the .NET Framework ECMA standard. [Stronger memory model](https://web.archive.org/web/20120310104629/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx) is actually implemented by the .NET Framework runtime. An alternative definition is described by [Joe Duffy](https://web.archive.org/web/20071208141010/http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2007/11/10/CLR20MemoryModel.aspx). One practical case where the .NET memory model makes difference to Java one is described on the [IKVM.NET blog](http://weblog.ikvm.net/PermaLink.aspx?guid=ea28365e-947e-4e00-a969-d8c8a29b3a42).

Regarding your points:

1. Locking works the same way as in Java.
2. Safe publication - The first two scenarios (locks and [volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) work identical to the Java counterparts.

   Synchronized collections in .NET are deprecated, but they internally use a lock, so they work exactly the same way as if the accesses were locked.

   [Concurrent collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) added as part of .NET 3.5 internally use lock-free techniques, so they should be memory coherent between different threads. I'm not sure if they are memory consistent though.
3. Immutable object are thread-safe by definition. Once you construct an immutable object it can no longer be modified. The thread that created it is the only thread that can have its copy in the cache. Once you publish it, all the other threads will get an up-to-date copy and this copy is guaranteed not to change. Thus, the only sore point is the publishing itself. You still need to care about Safe publication in order not to create two instances of the immutable object, but each of these instances would be thread-safe when accessed from any thread.

Comment: An interesting article about the .NET memory model is available at http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/. According to it, the .NET memory model differs from Java by treating writes to ordinary variables as volatile. If that was the only difference than all Java algorithms should work fine in .NET. The reverse wouldn't necessarily be true though.

Comment: Do you know how thread safety for immutable objects works? According to the Bloch book immutable objects are thread safe regardless of how they are published. He gives an example of lazy initialization in the section on the memory model where the reference to the lazy initialized variable is neither final, volatile or locked.

Comment: Once you construct an immutable object it can no longer be modified. The thread that created it is the only thread that can have its memory cached. Once you publish it all the other threads will get an up-to-date copy and this copy is guaranteed not to change. Thus, the only sore point is the publishing itself. This gets back to point 2 about Safe publication.

Comment: Which example (listing nr.) in the book are you referring to? 16.4. works because of the "synchronized" keyword on the method (eg. it's locked); 16.5. works because static constructors are guaranteed to run only once and always before the first instance is created (same in Java and .NET); 16.6. is lazy version of 16.5; 16.7 can be published using unsynchronized variable because at worst you'd create a second instance of the same immutable object. It's be still safe to access from any thread, but it'd be different copy.

Comment: He mentions in section 16.3 that unsafe lazy initialization (guess he means listing 16.3) or even publication to a public field can be used safely. It seems to me that he is saying that the guarantees for immutable objects are stronger than for effectively immutable ones i.e. somehow references to these objects can shared between threads without the need for synchronization.

Comment: Section 16.3. states that the immutable object itself is safe to be accessed from any thread. If the unsafe lazy initialization is used there's still a risk that two copies of the immutable object will be created, but each of these copies would be consistent when accessed by the respective thread. The guarantee that he describes is that if final (readonly) fields are used then their values are explicitly guaranteed to be visible to all threads by the time the constructor finishes. I believe that in .NET this property is true even for non-final fields (per the igoro.com article linked above).

Comment: He also says that it safe to publish via a public field in this case only one object would be created the worry would be in java case at least the a thread than the creating one would see a null value for the reference. Maybe what he means is if you have an reference to an immutable object then you can be sure it's contents are up to date but if that's the case why distinguish between immutable and effectively immutable as you still need to publish the reference safely in general (in the LI case 2 copies may not always be ok). It's not 100% clear to me - probably better to lock etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried to construct a happens-before model, but I have implemented lock-free data structures in .Net (lock-free ring buffer, most recently).

References published from volatile variables are guaranteed to be 'safe', the volatile keyword in .Net forces a direct-from-memory read of that reference, and forces any change to that reference to be direct-to-memory write.

Comparing two volatile variables to each other may result in stale conclusions however. In the lock-free ring buffer I wrote, this was not a problem. The enqueue method would occasionally think the buffer was full when it was one item shy (dequeue happens just as i compare my volatile head and tail pointers); the dequeue method would occasionally think the buffer was empty for the same reason. However, in my case, no data was lost.

So to answer your sort-of general question, implementing lock-free data structures in .Net is certainly possible, I've done it, and without much pain.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about comparing volatile variables - are you saying the contents of the objects they reference are alway seen as up to date but the value of such variables (i.e. which objects they point to) may not be?